# Query mongoid string with brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have mongoid field '***value***' as string like "**Sivatha (St. 329)**", and I use regex for querying the value via ajax as the following:

```
Street.any_of({ :value => /.*#{params[:q]}.*/i }))
```

It raises errors while my params value is "**Sivatha (St.**" while I am typing, and It doesn't return result at all when I have exact value "**Sivatha (St. 329)**".

Can anybody here give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be quoting strings with [`Regexp.quote`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-quote) before interpolating them into a regex:

```
:value => /.*#{Regexp.quote(params[:q])}.*/i
```

You don't need the leading and trailing `.*`, they don't do anything for you, so you could just say:

```
:value => /#{Regexp.quote(params[:q])}/i
```

If you weren't using a case-insensitive regex then you could use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to quote and regex-ify your string all at once:

```
:value => Regexp.union(params[:q])
```

but there's no clean way to add the `/i` option to that so `/#{Regexp.quote(params[:q])}/i` is probably the cleanest thing you can do.

Comment: Yeah thanks all :-) I got it worked very well. I also found **Regexp.escape(params[:q])** which produces result exactly the same as **Regexp.quote(params[:q])**